# Creating Search/filter in express mongo react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

im trying to build a filter menu to filter the incoming data from mongodb.
im using the .find(); function to limit the incoming data.

usage like this
`Post.find({boatType: "Cruiser"})`

So here is what ive got so far.
I transfer the data that i need to filter via query

```
const res = await axios.get(`/api/posts/`,
            {
                params: {
                    hull: "Catamaran",
                    boatType: "Cruiser",
                    seller: "Private",
                    etc..
                }
            });
```

express Backend

```
const posts = await Post.find({exampleField: "exampleFilter"});
```

and this is where im stuck. After i pass the queries to the node backend, i have no idea how to get the .find() function to work across multiple fields. and even more confusing for me is that these queries will be dynamic. Sometimes the "hull" query will not be there, or it might be that "seller" is not there, etc etc. Is there a better way to do what im doing? Should i be using $Regex or $in... im lost and the documentation is doing me no favors.

all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

you should just pass your query object to `Post.find()`, like this:

```
app.get('/api/posts' , (req, res) => {
    // you can access the query from req.query
    const posts = await Post.find(req.query);
})
```

You can check [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) and [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) for more details.

Comment: THANK YOU! 
the only thing not working now is if i use 
 ```` {condition: "like new"}```` the space in the String wont work right

Comment: you mean you have a document like `{ ... , condition: "like new" , ...}` and `Post.find({ condition: "like new"})` won't find it?